# Java system.load() in a while loop

Tags: java, dll, while-loop

```
int d = 0;

while( d < 5 ) {
    System.load(PATH-OF-THE-DLL-IN-HERE.DLL(returned_by_another_function_as_string));
    d++;
}
```

Trying to load a msgbox DLL multiple times. The above code works fine but i have 2 questions on it. 1) Why System.load() loads it only once and then exits? 2) Why the JAR is still running until i close the msgbox?

Any way to avoid those issues? For example, to load the same msgbox DLL 5-6 times with system.load?

Comment: Why do you want to load a DLL multiple times? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to accomplish the DLL execution more than once by using system.load(). No funcy projects.

Comment: A DLL is a library, with some functions stored in it. You don't need to load it multiple times. Load it one time, and call 5 times the same function

Comment: I know what a DLL is :) i wrote the DLL i'm calling. I just want to call it multiple times.

Comment: So call it multiple times. That doesn't mean you have to load it multiple times. Java won't let you do that, and neither will the operating system. Subsequent loads just increment usage counts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) Why System.load() loads it only once and then exits?

Because that's the way it should work, it doesn't have sense loading the same library more than once (why would you want to have the same program instructions more than once spending memory?) `System.load()` calls `Runtime.getRuntime().load0()` internally, which calls `ClassLoader.loadLibrary0()`, which validates wether the library has already been loaded, if so, then just return.

> 2) Why the JAR is still running until I close the msgbox?

because the native code hasn't finish its execution. The JVM won't finish until all its non-daemon threads have finished.

I'm just guessing, but I think you're showing that msgbox int the dll's entry point function. If that's the case, instead of this you should show your msgbox in a native function that you can call multiple times so you can have your 5 msgboxes.